# C# вк код подтверждения

Tags: c#, .net, vkontakte-api, vknet

После ввода паролья  и логина приходит сообщение с Код подтверждения входа от администрации вк а как сделать поля для в вода этого кода ?

```
{
    int appID = ******;
    string nomer = login.Text;
    string password = pass.Text;
    Settings settings = Settings.All;

    VkApi.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
    {
        ApplicationId = 6492276,
        Login = nomer,
        Password = password,
        Settings = Settings.All
    });
```

Comment: Уважаемый, а вы [документацию](https://vknet.github.io/vk/authorize/) вообще читали? Ведь в ней все сказано, а то вы уже 3-й вопрос задаете, которых у вас не возникло бы, если читали бы документацию...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в документации не написано про код подтверждения.

Comment: Ну как это "не написано". Прямым текстом `Для двухфакторной авторизации необходимо передать пятым параметром обработчик, возвращающий код авторизации.`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ В любом случаи я работаю с windows Form а там кансоль

Comment: И что вам мешает из WinForms перекинуть нужное? Любая библиотека имеет свой стандарт по которому с ней идет работа. Смена платформы на подобное не как не влияет. Вам в документации явно сказано - передавайте пятым параметром обработчик, так делайте этот обработчик.